# Return code of shell start script which launches task on background

Tags: bash, shell

I'm seeking for an advice regarding the best practice of starting (java) programs from shell scripts.

Currently the practice within our firm seems to be having a shell script which sets all the environment variables and launches the java (which is not important in this case) process on background similar to:

```
nohup $JAVA_CMD > $LOG_DIR/$LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
```

which is the last line of the script. We are launching single process.

One doubt I have is that return code of such shell process is always 0 even for the case when the program fails to start due to some Exception/Error. This makes it hard for monitoring tools - they can't rely on the shell exit code for example.

I found out this can be fixed by waiting for the process to end like:

```
nohup $JAVA_CMD > $LOG_DIR/$LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
wait $!
```

But my understanding is that this makes the last `&` completely useless since running:

```
nohup $JAVA_CMD > $LOG_DIR/$LOG_FILE 2>&1
```

will have the same effect.

So my question is: what is the best practice of launching programs from shell? Does the running on background have some benefits I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into at and batch, and possibly cron.  These are all tools to run commands scripts, job streams non-interactively.  at runs a job then emails stderr output back to the user - default behavior.

```
at -k now <<!
$JAVA_CMD > $LOG_DIR/$LOG_FILE 2>&1
!
```

The batch command  will let you write a series of commands to a file, then execute the file as if it were stdin, you can also do this interactively.

cron jobs (crontab) run at specified times and dates, like every Monday at 0200.  This does not seem to fit your question.

Try this:

```
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/at-atq-atrm-batch-command-examples/
```